# C Program that determines whether a number is prime or not using a recursive function

Tags: c, function, recursion, primes

The program I am trying to create should print whether a number scanned from the keyboard is prime or not. The program should use a recursive function for determining whether the number is prime or not. The program I have created has no compiling issues. However, when the main() function calls the function for determining if the number is prime or not (I called this function isprime), it seems to return that the integer scanned from the keyboard is always prime. This is the case for both prime and non prime numbers. The program I created looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//function for determining whether a number is prime or not
int isprime(int i, int n){
    i = 2; 
    if(n > 1){
        /* i = 2, i is the divisor that checks whether n (the number
        being checked for being prime) is in fact prime */
        if(n % i == 0){
            return 1; 
        }
        /* recursive step that returns function with increased value
        of i */
        isprime(i + 1, n);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    int x;
    //scans integer from the keyboard
    scanf("%d", &x);
    //calls recursive function 
    if(isprime(2, x) == 1){
        printf("%d is prime\n", x);
    }
    if(isprime(2, x) == 0){
        printf("%d is not prime\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One last question: is calling a recursive function like in my program:

```
 isprime(2, x)
```

the right syntax to use? Is it correct to insert the number 2 directly into the argument of the function?

Any help is appreciated!:)

Comment: I don't think the definition of prime is `n % i == 0`

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-program-prime-number/

Comment: `if(isprime(2, x) == 1)` then you know enough. Why call it again in the else part?

Comment: regarding: `int isprime(int i, int n){
    i = 2; `   Why change the first parameter from ... to 2, especially when call calls to `isprime()` always, already set the first parameter to 2?

Comment: note also that in the return value of the recursive call to `isprime()` is ignored.

Comment: regarding: `if(isprime(2, x) == 1){
        printf("%d is prime\n", x);
    }
    if(isprime(2, x) == 0){
        printf("%d is not prime\n", x);`   It is a waste to call `isprime()` more than once.  Suggest: `if(isprime(2, x) == 1){
        printf("%d is prime\n", x);
    } else {
        printf("%d is not prime\n", x);

Comment: in the `isprime()` function, this call: `isprime(i + 1, n);` is ignoring the returned value.  This is an error

Comment: `1` is neither prime nor composite. Therefore, you can't `return 0` when you encounter `1`.

Comment: in function: `isprime()`,  regarding the statements: `i = 2;` and `isprime(i + 1, n);`  No matter what the value of `i` is set to, it is always 'reset' to 2 at the top of the function,   This is an error

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. checks for and handles I/O errors
4. incorporates the comments to the OPs question
5. reversed the meaning of a returned value of 0 or 1 for ease of calculation
6. properly implements a recursive algorithm, including edge cases and stop condition
7. could greatly limit the recursion depth by utilizing the sqrt of 'n' as a limiting factor for the parameter 'i'
8. uses 'unsigned' values to avoid the complications of negative numbers

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int isprime( unsigned i, unsigned n )
{
    if( n < 2 )
    { // cannot be prime
        return 1;  
    }

    if( i >= n )
        return 0;

    if(n % i == 0)
    {  // then, not prime
        return 1; 
    }

    return isprime(i + 1, n );
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned x;
    if( scanf("%u", &x) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    if( !isprime(2, x ) )
    {
        printf("%d is prime\n", x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is not prime\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any justification in your code for "reversed the meaning of a returned value of 0 or 1 for ease of calculation".  Which "calculation" is eased?  I just see confusion when `isPrime(n)` returns truthy when `n` is not a prime!

Comment: @cdlane,  If you don't want to use the '1' means not prime, then don't.  However, usually, in linux, a return of 0 indicates success and any other value indicates a failure.

Comment: I thought the convention is that something named `is_X(n)` is a boolean predicate and returns truthy if `n` is X and falsey if `n` isn't X.  Reading `if (! isprime(2, x )) printf("%d is prime\n", x);` out loud doesn't work for me.  (I've a similar issue with `if (! strcmp(...))` expressions.)

Answer (score 0):

An example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int is_prime(int n, int div)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 0;
    else if (div <= 1)
        return 1;
    else if (n % div == 0)
        return 0;
    return is_prime(n, --div);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("%d is %s\n", i, is_prime(i, (int)(sqrt(i)))? "prime":"not prime");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The two arguments which you need to pass is the number to be checked, and its square root. You do not need to check numbers greater than this because if you think about it, there is really no need to.
For example if your number is 16 you will only need to check numbers from 1 to 4. Kind of hard to explain so here is a table:

```
1*16
2*8
4*4
8*2 <----- We already checked this!!
...
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you deal with argument testing (negative input) and special cases (even numbers other than 2) in a general `is_prime()` function but once your data is clean, turn the calculation over to a focused `is_prime_recursive()` function, avoiding redundant tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_prime_recursive(unsigned number, unsigned odd_divisor)
{
    if (odd_divisor * odd_divisor > number) {
        return true;
    }

    if (number % odd_divisor == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return is_prime_recursive(number, odd_divisor + 2);
}

bool is_prime(int number)
{
    if (number <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return (2 == number);
    }

    return is_prime_recursive(number, 3);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        printf("%d is %sprime\n", i, is_prime(i) ? "" : "not ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program I created that prints out whether a number is prime or not using a recursive function for determining so! The comments in the program explain each part! Hopefully this helps anyone trying to create a similar program!

```
#include <stdio.h>
// i = divisor
// n = number being checked for being prime
int isprime(int i, int n){
    //base case one: 1 is not prime
    if (n == 1){
        return 0;
    }
    //base case two: 2 is prime 
    if (n == 2){
        return 1;
    }
    //if i is a divisor then n not prime 
    if (n % i == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    /* if root of n is reached while trying 
    to find a divisor but no divisor found, so 
    no previous return, then we have a prime number */
    if (i * i > n){
        return 1;
    }
    //recursive step, trying next value as divisor
    return isprime(i + 1, n);
}

int main(){
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if(isprime(2, x) == 1){
        printf("%d is prime\n", x);
    }
    if(isprime(2, x) == 0){
        printf("%d is not prime\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input for this program looks like this:

```
3
```

The output of this program looks like this:

```
3 is prime
```